# Making an object that can be called as a function

Tags: javascript

I would like a object (lets call it `jquery` for an example) that I can call by `jquery.subFunction()` and `jquery().subfunction()`.

Can this be done in any good way?

Example object:

```
var jquery = {
    selfFunction: function(){
        // this is the main function which is runned with `jquery()`
    },

    subFunction: function(){
        // something
    }
};
```

Why `jquery` as example? Cause they do it.

Comment: A function *is* an object that can be called as a function...

Comment: you can't call a custom object (one with a bunch of prototype methods), but you can (with many caveats) attach named properties to function instances, as others have shown. do watch your names because function instance property names are heavily polluted compared to objects (ex: bind, length, prototype, name, displayName, arity, caller, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

functions are objects, so you can attach methods and properties to them

```
var jQuery = function() {
    return {
        subfunction : function() {
             // do stuff
        }
    }
}

jQuery.subfunction = function() {
    // do stuff
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4d1ponjx/)